# Redirect page after login with next-auth middleware

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, google-signin, next-auth

I want to use next-auth middleware to proteced all pages. I set up the middleware by looking at the official documentation([next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware)) of next-auth and confirmed that it redirects without being logged in.

However, when I am logged in, it is still redirecting to the login page.

Please let me know what i have done wrong

[...nextauth].ts

```js
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import client from "@/libs/server/client";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { Session } from "next-auth/";

interface UserSession extends Session {
  id: string;
}
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(client),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, user }) => {
      (session as UserSession).id = user.id;
      return session;
    },
    redirect: ({ url, baseUrl }) => {
      return baseUrl;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/enter",
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

middleware.ts

```js
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/mypage","/with", "/product/:path*"],
};
```

Comment: In order to determine the issue it would also be necessary to see where the actual authentication logic itself is. It could be that the middleware is fine and the authentication process itself isn't properly configuring your session.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by setting session strategy and adding jwt to callback.

```js
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import client from "@/libs/server/client";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(client),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt({ token, account, profile }: any) {
      if (account) {
        console.log("token", token);
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        token.id = profile.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
    session({ session, token }: any) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.id = token.sub;
      return session;
    },
    redirect({baseUrl}) {
      return baseUrl;
    }
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/enter",
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```